# Turning off matching in Google Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, aop, guice

I currently have a `Module` impl that uses the following binding:

```
binder.bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(), Matchers.any(),
    new WidgetInterceptor());
```

I want to be able to programmatically toggle this functionality on/off, and here's what I've cooked up:

```
private boolean widgetInterceptionEnabled = true;

public void configure(Binder binder) {
    Matcher<Object> matcher = null;
    if(widgetInterceptionEnabled)
        matcher = Matchers.any();
    else
        matcher = Matchers.not(Matchers.any());

    binder.bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(), matcher,
        new WidgetInterceptor());
}
```

Is this the correct way to tell Guice *not* to match anything? Or am I using the API wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't this be simpler?:

```
public void configure(Binder binder) {

    if(widgetInterceptionEnabled){
        binder.bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(), Matchers.any(),
            new WidgetInterceptor());
    }

}
```

Comment: Yup! Always nice to have a fresh perspective!